# Error de carga Glide en Adapter usando en PHP procesamientos almacenados

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide, glide

estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto relacionado a app de compras, decidí actualizar mi Código php usando procesamientos almacenados, en una de mis actividades donde muestro los productos con un RecyclerView y un Adapter, sucede que cuando actualicé el archivo PHP que realizaba la consulta a través de un procesamiento almacenado dentro de un prepare(),en el emulador la 3º ves que vuelvo a la actividad no se carga. Cuando volví a realizar la consulta en el archivo php **sin**procesamiento almacenados el problema despareció.
Les muestro:
https://youtu.be/MEA67JR0QUk

Este es mi codigo php:

```
 <?php

require_once 'conexion.php';


//$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Producto");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL spListaProducto");
$stmt ->execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($id,$nombre, $precio, $img);

$productos = array();

while($stmt ->fetch()){

    $temp = array();
    $temp['id'] = $id;
    $temp['nombre'] = $nombre;
    $temp['precio'] = $precio;
    $temp['img'] = $img;
    

    array_push($productos,$temp);
    }

    echo json_encode($productos);

?>
```

Este es la parte del Adapter que carga la imagen con Glide:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.nombre_tab.setText(productoList.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.precio_tab.setText(productoList.get(position).getPrecio());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(productoList.get(position).getImg())
                .into(holder.imagen_tab);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Intent intent=new Intent(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(),DetalleProducto.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemProducto",producto);
                viewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);*/
                //Producto producto=productoList.get(position);
                int id;
                String nombre,precio,img;
                id=productoList.get(position).getId();
                nombre=holder.nombre_tab.getText().toString();
                precio=holder.precio_tab.getText().toString();
                img=productoList.get(position).getImg();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "ID: "+id+"\nNombre: "+nombre+"\nPrecio: "+precio+"\nIMG: "+img, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),DetalleTablaActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("itemProducto", producto.get);
                intent.putExtra("id",id);
                intent.putExtra("nombre",nombre);
                intent.putExtra("precio",precio);
                intent.putExtra("img",img);
                holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                //context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
```

Y este es la advertencia que me muestra el Run:

```
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
```

Alguien sabe porque se presenta este error de carga cuando uso un proceso almacenado?

Comment: Primero, son `procedimientos de almacenado o store procedure`. Segundo, ¿Cómo estas importando `Glide` a tu proyecto?

Comment: `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'`

Answer (score 0):

La forma de instanciar Glide actualmente es diferente, probablemente eso sea el problema al cargar las imagenes

Primeramente crea una clase `GlideApp` en tu proyecto:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class GlideApp extends AppGlideModule {

}
```

ahora **en tu proyecto en lugar de usar la clase `Glide` debes usar la clase `GlideApp` para cargar las imagenes** :

```
 GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(productoList.get(position).getImg())
                .into(holder.imagen_tab);
```

Comment: Creé la clase, pero ahora me dice que el metodo "with" no existe en GladeApp. Ademas me dice esto una vez intento ejecutar el proyecto, `> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.example.login.GlideApp
`

Comment: Cuales son las dependencias que usas en tu build.gradle?

Comment: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation('com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'`